# <Return> Key binding doesn't work at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I'm coding a simple gui with tkinter and python. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class migrate_tk(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):           
        self.grid()                 

        self.entry = Entry(self)                            
        self.entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='EW')       
        #~ self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)        
        #~ self.bind('<Return>', self.OnPressEnter)

        label = Label(self, anchor="w", fg="white", bg="blue")
        label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="EW")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)          

        self.resizable(True, False)                     

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        print ("You pressed enter")
        if self.label["bg"] == "blue":
            self.label["bg"] = "yellow"
        else: self.label["bg"] = "blue"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = migrate_tk(None)
    app.title('app') 
    app.mainloop()
```

The problem is that pressing the return key, it doesn't print anything (obviously i run it into a terminal)
Thanks!

Comment: If you could reduce your example down to just the necessary code to explain the question, that would help.

Comment: When I run your code I get a stack trace, but I _also_ get "You pressed enter") and the label changes to yellow. So it seems that the binding is working fine. You're forgetting to assign `self.label`, however, which is the reason you're getting a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you might be getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'label'
```

& the reason for that is:
you have to do this while declaring `label`:

```
self.label = Label(self, anchor="w", fg="white", bg="blue")
self.label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="EW")
```

Down below you were using label as an instance of class `migrate_tk` but not when you declared it

The enter widget doesn't get focus automatically,so when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without selecting the widget,it doesn't do anything.

What you need to do is un-comment the code:

```
self.entry.focus_set()
```

& It will work fine after that.

Comment: I understand the label error, but not why the print command of OnPressEnter doesn't work.
Anyways, I don't get the attribute error.

Comment: well that's the error i was getting when running your program(& it is an error!). Also,its working exactly like its supposed to be when i removed this error .Kindly share what error you got

Comment: I'm using xubuntu 14.04 and python3 (same on python2.7). It doesn't print any error. The only thing it prints is "You clicked the button!" 

could be a system-key binding error or some similar?
but it's strange, it's occurring just here!

Comment: When you click the button it **is** gonna say _You clicked the button!_ & do nothing else, as there is nothing else there in _OnButtonClick()_

Comment: sorry I meant the function OnPressEnter doesn't print anything.

i just edited the source removing OnButtonClick to be clear

Comment: I'm sorry but after adding `self` to the label,it **is** printing _You pressed enter_ & also the color is changing to Yellow.

Comment: Okay, maybe the problem is you are not entering any value & just pressing enter(though that's not the problem). So,it is not getting the focus

Comment: ok, I've been hasty.
Solved :)
thanks for your patience

Comment: @bomba : if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.